# Array index out of bounds in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I want to declare an Array with 4 dimensions, then loop some stuff with `for()` - and then the program breaks. Here is my code:

Typescript:

```
MoarInfo: any = [[[[]]]];
```

JavaScript:

```
constructor(){
 for(var i = 0; i < this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth].length; i++){
  for(var a = 0; a < this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i].length; a++){
    for(var b = 0; b < this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i][a].length; b++){

      this.MoarInfo[i][a][b][0] = this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i][a][b][0];
      this.MoarInfo[i][a][b][1] = this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i][a][b][1];
      this.MoarInfo[i][a][b][2] = 'DetailsSpan';

    }
  }
}
}
```

The Problem definitively lies at the `MoarInfo[][][][]` array. I tested my code without it, and it works fine. I tried the following possibilities for the Typescript array declaration as well:

```
Moarinfo: any[]; MoarInfo = []; MoarInfo = [[[[]]]]; MoarInfo: any[][][][] = [[[[]]]];
```

And in JavaScript, I tried to declare a new Array, and then push some elements on the `MoarInfo` array, with different functions (split, unshift, push, concat) and nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of `this.MoarInfo[i][a][b]`. You are trying to get the value by index 0,1,2. Looks like its size is less than 2 which is causing this error.

```
      if(this.MoarInfo[i][a][b].size > 0){
         this.MoarInfo[i][a][b][0] = this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i][a][b][0];
      }
       if(this.MoarInfo[i][a][b].size > 1){
           this.MoarInfo[i][a][b][1] = this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i][a][b][1];
       }
       if(this.MoarInfo[i][a][b].size > 2){
           this.MoarInfo[i][a][b][2] = 'DetailsSpan';
       }
```

Comment: I guess with `this.MoarInfo[i][a][b].length`? In this case its 0. `this.MoarInfo[i][a].length` is 1 and `this.MoarInfo[i].length` is 1 aswell. And yeah, you are right!

Comment: Then better would be to have check for index before you access sit. Updated the answer with the same.

Comment: Thank's for you answer man, but this avoids just the error, I would much appreciate it, if the Array would save the values I tell him to ^^

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out for myself. You have to set the `elements` of the `dimensions` from the `array` at first blank, then you can fill them with content. First I declared an `Array` in `TypeScript` like this `AnArray = [];`. Then I switched to `JavaScript` ( to the `constructer()` function ) and filled it with blank `elements`. I archieved this with `this.AnArray.push();`. If you want to set `elements` for the first `dimension` use `push([]);`, if you want an `element` for the 4th `dimension`, use `push([[[]]]);`. And you can set your content space like this `push([[['E1',0,0,'E2']]]);`. Now you can use follwing syntax:

```
alert( this.AnArray[0][0][0][3] ); //returns 'E2'
```

The complete code from my project now works fine and looks like this:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth].length; i++){
  this.test.push([[[]]]);

  for(var a = 0; a < this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i].length; a++){
    this.test[i].push([[]]);

    for(var b = 0; b < this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i][a].length; b++){
      this.test[i][a].push(['',0,'']);

      this.test[i][a][b][0] = this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i][a][b][0];
      this.test[i][a][b][1] = this.AllDataInfo[this.KontoAktuellYearIndex][this.KontoAktuellMonth][i][a][b][1];
      this.test[i][a][b][2] = 'DetailsSpan';

    }
  }
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way than using arrays, but if you want it too, you can do it like this.

- cheers